# Vscode move to line X after openTextDocument

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VS Code extension that jump to a specific **file:num**, but I'm stuck at the step of moving the cursor to a specific line after opening a file.
How can I achieve this :

```
export const openAndMoveToLine = async (file_line: string) => {

  // /home/user/some/path.php:10
  let [filename, line_number] = file_line.split(":")
  
  // opening the file => OK
  let setting: vscode.Uri = vscode.Uri.parse(filename)
  let doc = await vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(setting)
  vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, 1, false);

  // FIXME: After being opened, now move to the line X  => NOK **/

  await vscode.commands.executeCommand("cursorMove",     {
          to: "down", by:'wrappedLine',
          value: parseInt(line_number)
    });

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with the [TextDocumentShowOptions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocumentShowOptions) easily:

```js
const showDocOptions = {
    preserveFocus: false,
    preview: false,
    viewColumn: 1,

    // replace with your line_number's
    selection: new vscode.Range(314, 0, 314, 0)
};

let doc = await vscode.window.showTextDocument(setting, showDocOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to get access to the active editor. This is done by adding a `.then` to the `showTextDocument` call (which is a `Thenable` function) that returns a text editor object. You will then be able to use the `textEditor` variable (as in the example) to set the position of the cursor using the `selection` property as follows:

```
vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc, 1, false).then((textEditor: TextEditor) => {
  const lineNumber = 1;
  const characterNumberOnLine = 1;
  const position = new vscode.Position(lineNumber, characterNumberOnLine);
  const newSelection = new vscode.Selection(position, position);
  textEditor.selection = newSelection;
});
```

Reference to `selection` API can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Selection).

The usecase that you are exploring has been discussed in GitHub issue that can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111).